# How to Joi-Allow an empty Date String [Joi]

Tags: javascript, date, validation, joi

as the title states, how to allow an empty Date-String through Joi validation.

**When adding:**

```
Date: ""
```

**it gets the Issue**: `message: ""Date" must be a number of milliseconds or valid date string"`

with this **Joi-Validation:**

```
"Date": Joi.date().required().allow("").allow(null).options(validationErrors);
```

**Question**: How can an empty Date-String be allowed through Joi validation?

**EDIT**: By removing: `.required()` and or adding `.default("")` i do get another error, when adding `Date: ""`, `Cannot set parameter at row: 1. Wrong input for DATE type`

Comment: Remove `.required()` and set a `.default("")` So you have a input if the user specify nothing, and a valid timestamp when the user do

Comment: I added new information to EDIT.

Comment: There is no "EDIT"

Comment: Wrong box, check again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valid: Either `new Date()` or `""` (empty string)

`joi` version **17.2.1**

```js
const joi = require('joi');

const schema = joi.object().keys({
  "Date": joi.alternatives([
    joi.date(),
    joi.string().valid('')
  ]).required()
}).required();

// success
const value = {
  "Date": "",
};

// success
const value = {
  "Date": new Date(),
};

// error
const value = {
  "Date": null,
};

// error
const value = {

};

// error
const value = {
  "Date": "invalid string"
};


const report = schema.validate(value);
console.log(report.error);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply remove `required()` from the above code.

```
"Date": Joi.date().allow("").allow(null).options(validationErrors);
```